# ruby - Permutation between elements of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coding a plugin in Google Sketchup with ruby and I faced a real problem while trying to permute two arrays that are present in an array all this depending on a user combination.

> I have an array of arrays like `[["1"],["lol"], ["so"]]`
>
> When we have a combination like this <`[1,
>   2, 3]` it's fine, it should stay the same : `[["1"],["lol"], ["so"]]`
>
> But when we have a combination like this `[2, 3, 1]`, the output should be : `[["lol"], ["so"], ["1"]]`
>
> For `[3,1,2]` => `[["so"], ["1"], ["lol"]]`
>
> ...etc

**EDIT**
Sorry guys I forgot for the array I have a bit like : `[["1, 2, 3"], ["lol1, lol2, lol3"], ["so1, so2, so3"]]` so for the combination `[2, 3, 1]` the output should be : `[["2, 3, 1"], ["lol2, lol3, lol1"], ["so2, so3, so1"]]`

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: A bit complicated; i've tried deleting the useless elements : delete_at() to have just the [["lol"]]. and then push the ["so"] and ["1"] but it didn't work for either with a.push or << or even array+array.

Answer (score 4):

You could use collect:

```
array   = [["1"],["lol"], ["so"]]
indexes = [2, 1, 3]
indexes.collect {|i| array[i-1]} #=> [["lol"], ["1"], ["so"]]
```

If you set the indexes to be 0-based you could drop the -1

split and map can be used to turn your strings into values:

```
"1, 2, 3".split(",").map { |i| i.to_i} # [1, 2, 3]
```

You can then also split your strings

```
"lol2, lol3, lol1".split(/, /) #=> ["lol2", "lol3", "lol1"]
```

You should be able to put that together with the above to get what you want.

Comment: Arg, well, you got there first

Comment: I'm sorry, please see EDIT. Your code is working for '[["1"],["lol"], ["so"]]' array but not for the '[["1, 2, 3"], ["lol1, lol2, lol3"], ["so1, so2, so3"]]' array. Sorry for the changes.

Comment: @Paul Rubel It didn't work for me, since i'm dealing with a lot of arrays contained in an array like `[["lol1, lol2, lol3"], ["lol4, lol5, lol6"], ["lol7, lol8, lol9"], ...]`

Answer (score 1):

```
indexes = [2, 1, 3]
array   = [["1"],["lol"], ["so"]]
result  = indexes.map{|index| array[index-1] }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot something, please see EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at active_enum

https://github.com/adzap/active_enum

You could do something like:

```
class YourClassName < ActiveEnum::Base
  value [1] => ['1']
  value [2] => ['lol'] 
  value [3] => ['so']
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, please see EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [["1"], ["lol"], ["so"]]
index = [2, 1, 3]

index.collect {|i| a[i - 1]}
```

This outputs

```
[["lol"], ["1"], ["so"]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot something, please see EDIT.